# Uploading to S3 from Laravel Quality Lost

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My application uploads images to s3. I use front-end rendering to get the colors of the image, but because uploading to s3 lowers the quality (jpeg'ish), I get more colors then desired.

[image]

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->put('/images/file.jpg', '/images/file.jpg', 'public');
```

Is there way to prevent this quality loss? I noticed that if I upload the file directly using aws console website, the quality stays the same which is ideal.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you test/validate this apparent quality loss ? As far as I understand, files won't have this quality loss by default.

Comment: S3 has no mechanism that would alter the payload of an uploaded object in any way.  Whatever is happening here can only be external to S3.

Comment: Laravel's `put` won't do this either. Something else is going on.

Comment: Is there more code surrounding the code provided?

Comment: That's really just it. I'm using Laravel's services to upload the file ad documented. I save one locally and to s3 and the s3 version has discounted quality.

Comment: That's quite literally impossible. The code you've shown does a direct byte-for-byte transfer of the file. Something else *must* be going on.

Comment: Can you list your installed packages as they are in `composer.json`?

Comment: Did you retrieved the files from S3 in the same manner, the one loaded to S3 via Laravel and the file uploaded using the AWS UI?  Since you indicated that the latter didn't show this quality degradation, then the we are assuming that it has to be the Laravel put that is causing the issue.  If that is the case, then what is happening to the file, before the put statement is executed?  Is the image shown above the original on the same server as the Laravel code?

Answer (score 4):

**In the controller Action**

```
public function uploadFileToS3(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('image');
}
```

Next we need to assign a file name to the uploaded file.You could leave this as the original filename, but in most cases you will want to change it to keep things consistent. Let’s change it to a timestamp, and append the file extension to it.

```
$imageFileName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Now get the image content as follows

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$filePath = '/images/file.jpg' . $imageFileName;
$s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
```

For further info you can refer to [this](https://chrisblackwell.me/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-laravel/)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Laravel but i am familiar with AWS S3, and i'm using [aws-sdk-php](https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php).

As far as i know, neither AWS S3 nor php-sdk don't do something implicitly under the hood. So it must be something going wrong elsewhere in your project.

You can try use plain aws-sdk-php:

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory([
    'region'      => 'us-west-2',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'version'     => 'latest',
]);
$s3->putObject([
    'Bucket'     => 'myBucket',
    'Key'        => 'test/img.jpg',
    'SourceFile' => '/tmp/img.jpg',
]);
```

It works perfectly.